# Android Jetpack Navigation BottomNavigationView and Login Screen

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, bottomnavigationview

hope everybody is doing great,

I came across an issue while using the Navigation Component from Jetpack.

Here's what I want to achieve:

I have a **LoginScreen** where the users will input their credentials and then I'll send them to the **MainScreen**, which by its turn has a *BottomNavigation*. (the BottomNavigation has been always there, I just hide it when the LoginScreen is visible).

Everything looks good until here, I can navigate from the LoginScreen to the MainScreen, and if the user presses back then the application gets closed.

But the problem starts when the user switches to a different tab, let's say, go from tab 1 to 2 them to 3. (1 -> 2 -> 3). If the user presses back, he'll see Screen 2 instead of Screen 1. But if I remove the LoginScreen and go straight to the MainScreen where I have the tabs, if I click on tab 1, 2, and then 3, if I press back, then I'll see the Screen1.

This is how the flow looks like:

[image]

Here's the [github repository](https://github.com/renanboni/NavComponent) which is basically a cloned from [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample) plus the LoginScreen.

Thanks a lot,
Cheers

Comment: Have you read the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) which specifically state that your Login screen should not be the start destination of your graph? What about the [guide specifically about implementing login](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login)?

Comment: I have not but THANKS for pointing that out, now that I read that single line I got all my problems sorted out, huge thanks mate